# Flutter ViewPager and PageTransformer

Tags: flutter

I want to implement something like [this from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275411/android-viewpager-preview-behind-view/37297108) in Flutter. Content will be dynamically created. I don't want to use flutter swiper because it has bugs and it is not maintained anymore. How can I implement this?

Another example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110483/android-vertical-view-pager-with-card-stack)

**Edit:** Let me clarify something: **I don't want** any code or work from you. Just asking the logic for how to do ViewPager and PageTransformer in Flutter. Because I tried PageView, Stack to implement this but I can not establish the logic.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. You must attempt the implementation yourself and then ask for help fixing any issues you may encounter. Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: go and look into the Swiper sources and you will see _logic for how to do ViewPager and PageTransformer in Flutter_